# Getting rid of double quotes inside array without turing array into a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, double, quotes

I have an array

> x=["1", "2", "3", ":*", ":+", "4", "5", ":-", ":/"]

I'm trying to get rid of the double quotation inside of the array.

I know I can use:

> x.to_s.gsub('"','')

and it will output a string:

> "[1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]"

The desired output I want is an array not a string:

> [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]

Is there a way for me to get rid of the double quotes for each element of the array but still leave my array as an array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should say that you want to replace each element of `x` with the corresponding integer or symbol (or somesuch), not that you want to "get rid of double quotes", which doesn't make sense.  Also, whereas you showed the output you don't want, you didn't show the result you do want.  You should do so (by editing your answer, not by adding comments).  You'll get the hang of it once you've been at SO for awhile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This is my first post. I edited my question to now include my desired output.Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
eval x.to_s.gsub('"', '')
# => [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

Comment: +1 I slightly prefer @Darren's answer, but you were the first to suggest use of (the dreaded) `eval`, which clearly is the way to go here.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way you can do it:

```
x=["1", "2", "3", ":*", ":+", "4", "5", ":-", ":/"]
=> ["1", "2", "3", ":*", ":+", "4", "5", ":-", ":/"]

x.map{|n|eval n}
=> [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

Important: The `eval` method is unsafe if you are accepting unfiltered input from an untrusted source (e.g. user input). If you are crafting your own array of strings, then `eval` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["1", "2", "3", ":*", ":+", "4", "5", ":-", ":/"]

x.map {|e| e[0] == ':' ? e[1..-1].to_sym : e.to_i}
```

or

```
x.map {|e| (e =~ /^\d+$/) ? e.to_i : e[1..-1].to_sym}

  # => [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

This of course only works when the elements of `x` are quoted integers and symbols (and I prefer the use of `eval`).