# Rails, delete string-quotes from array, without turning it to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a method, that takes an array as argument, such as:

```
a = ["title", "item"]
```

I need to get rid of the `"` but I have difficulties to do so.

My goal is to achieve the following:

```
a = [title, item]
```

Two possible solutions were presented here:[Getting rid of double quotes inside array without turing array into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834334/getting-rid-of-double-quotes-inside-array-without-turing-array-into-a-string)

```
eval x.to_s.gsub('"', '')
# => [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

and

```
x=["1", "2", "3", ":*", ":+", "4", "5", ":-", ":/"]
=> ["1", "2", "3", ":*", ":+", "4", "5", ":-", ":/"]

x.map{|n|eval n}
=> [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

I tried both of these solutions, but It always leads to this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `title'
```

How do I get rid off these " quotes in an array?

Edit:

I need to alter an array. This is what I am trying to do:

```
a = ["title", "item"]
```

should change to something like:

```
a = [model_class.human_attribute_name(:title), model_class.human_attribute_name(:title)]
```

(It's about translations).

This code is in a model.rb, maybe that helps.Here is my full code:

```
def humanifier(to_translate_array)
  translated = []

  to_translate_array.each do |element|
    translated.push("model_class.human_attribute_name(:#{element})")
  end


  return translated
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it? Are you expecting a specific data type? There's no way you can convert `"dog"` to `dog` unless `dog` is already defined as a variable. You could call `"dog".intern` but then that would give you the symbol `:dog` and you'd have to get rid of the colon.

It only displays with quotes because it's telling you its a string, when you actually print it out, it will not have quotes.

Comment: Please define your use case so we can better answer your question.

Comment: @jeff, edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to translate strings into symbols, you can do that with `#to_sym`

```
  to_translate_array.each do |element|
    translated.push("model_class.human_attribute_name(#{element.to_sym})")
  end
```

Or if you actually want the translated value, (and not just a string "model_class.human...")

```
  to_translate_array.each do |element|
    translated.push(model_class.human_attribute_name(element.to_sym))
  end
```

`"title"` is a string, `:title` is a symbol.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed

Comment: As an aside, `#intern` is an alias for `#to_sym` :)

Comment: @Jeff good point! Depends on your conceptual model... am I changing a string into a symbol?... am I changing a string into its internal representation?  It could be that OP would understand `#intern` better in his world view.